# How to auto open after Quarkus mvn clean compile quarkus:dev

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-reactive

Is there any possible configuration to auto open browser with the mentioned address and port after quarkus successfully compiles and is ready to serve.

Comment: There is no out of the box configuration, but it should be relatively easy to do with a custom extension